# Rails nested models optimised query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, optimization, mongoid4

**EDIT** : I'm using Mongoid, so no chaining nor `has_many through:`

I am developing a backend for project administration, and I have "deeply" related models

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :steps
  scope :active, ...

class Step
  has_many :assignments

class Assignment
  belongs_to :contractor, inverse_of: :project_assignment
  belongs_to :step

class Contractor
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :contractor_profile
  has_many :project_assignments, class_name: 'Assignment'

class User
  has_one :contractor_profile, class_name: 'Contractor'
```

Now, I have coded a sidebar for my users. In this sidebar, If the User has a contractor profile, I want to display the number of active projects

What would be the best way to implement an access to this information ?

We're talking about maybe up to 30 active projects at a time, from 1 to 6 assignments per project (but many steps with same contractors), and contractors usually have a few projects total (active or not).

My ideas :

- Look at the `current_contractor` assignments -> steps -> projects -> count active ones
- Look at active projects -> assignments -> Find contractors which match `current_contractor`
- Maybe add a `belong_to :project` (how can I ensure it's the same as `self.step.project` ?) in every Assignment to be able to jump Contractor -> assignments -> projects  & count

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to model a `has_many xxx though xxx` relation, but with 2 models involved in the `through`

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if about how you are using a presenter or a view directly, but from a model perspective, you should be able to do it chaining the activerecord associations (which it sounds like you already have in mind). For example

```
current_contractor.assignment.steps.projects.where(:status=>'active').count
```

You could refine this a little by making an active/inactive scope in the Projects model so then it would be

```
current_contractor.assignment.steps.projects.active.count
```

If this type of query is likely to be common, I'd consider creating a nested has_many_through relationship to go from contractor to projects, for example in the Contractor definition:

```
has_many :steps, 
       :through => :assignments
has_many :projects, :through => :steps
```

Then you could just do

```
contractor.projects.count
```

or if you've created the Project active/inactive scopes

```
contractor.projects.active.count
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Oh sorry, I added the tag, but forgot to mention it in the post. I'm using Mongoid not ActiveRecord, so no `has_many :through` :(. And no, unfortunately, I cannot chain associations. If I do `current_contractor.assignments.steps` I get a `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'assignments' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000008979ed0>):`

Comment: This solution uses invalid syntax and association calls.